# SSH error in MapReduce in EC2 host

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, mapreduce

I have installed Apache Hadoop MapReduce 2.6.1 in an Amazon EC2 host and I have configured the runtime with the private IP address. You can check my configuration below [2-5].

To try to ease debugging my problem, I have allowed all inbound traffic in the Security Groups [6].

The problem is that when I start MapReduce I get `Permission denied` in the SSH keys.

1. I have noticed that I can't `ssh` the EC host from same host. How do I fix this error? `ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX: ssh ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX`
2. I want to copy data between HDFS instances that are running in different sites in EC2. Is it correct to use the host`s private IP address?

[1] Error that I have

```
ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX:~/Programs/medusa-2.0$ start-all.sh 
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
15/12/16 10:52:18 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX]
ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX: Permission denied (publickey).
ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX: Permission denied (publickey).
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: Permission denied (publickey).
15/12/16 10:52:23 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /home/ubuntu/Programs/hadoop-2.6.2/logs/yarn-ubuntu-resourcemanager-ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX.out
ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX: Permission denied (publickey).
```

[2] Yarn-site.xml

```
ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX:~/Programs$ cat ./hadoop/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
<configuration>
 <property> <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name> <value>true</value> </property>
 <property> <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name> <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value> </property>  
 <property> <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name> <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value> </property>
 <property> <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name> <value>ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX:8025</value> </property>
 <property> <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name> <value>ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX:8030</value> </property>
 <property> <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name> <value>ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX:8040</value> </property>
</configuration>
```

[3] core-site.xml

```
ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX:~/Programs$ cat ./hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
<configuration>
  <property> <name>fs.default.name</name> <value>hdfs://ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX:9000</value> </property>
  <property> <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name> <value>/tmp/hadoop-temp</value> </property>
</configuration>
```

[4] slaves

```
ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX:~/Programs$ cat ./hadoop/etc/hadoop/slaves 
ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX
```

[5] SSH files

```
ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX:~/Programs$ ls -alrt ~/.ssh/
total 24
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  392 Dec 16 09:49 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  666 Dec 16 10:33 known_hosts
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  404 Dec 16 10:33 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1675 Dec 16 10:33 id_rsa
drwx------ 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Dec 16 10:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Dec 16 10:34 ..
```

[6] Security Groups

```
All traffic   All   All   0.0.0.0/0
SSH           TCP   22   0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 1):

It is related to SSH issue. You have not configured SSH properly.

You can test ssh ubuntu@ip**** before running start-all.sh program. If it is not working, then you need to resolve ssh issue and retry.

Comment: Yes, it is a SSH problem, but I think I have the right permissions in the files inside `~/.ssh`. Therefore, I don't get it why I can't do SSH?

Comment: Have you updated authorized keys with contents from id_rsa.pub?

Comment: Thanks, after I added `cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys`, the hadoop framework could start properly. I still have the problem about using private ips in MapReduce framework. I want to be able to copy files between 2 HDFS. Which ips should I use in the HDFS configuration so that I can copy files between 2 HDFS instances running in different hosts in EC2?

Comment: No, but I am imagining that I must use VPC to setup a VPN between different hosts and pay $0.05 per VPN Connection-hour, right?

Comment: If you are using VPC, you will not be able to communicate between the 2 instances if they are part of different instances. While communicating between instances you should always use private ips. With out VPC, you will be able to communicate between instances as long as they are in same region.

Comment: I think you mispelled your answer. You want to say that without VPC I won't be able to communicate between hosts in dfferent sites, right?

Comment: If you have VPC and if 2 instances running on different VPCs, then they cannot communicate with each other with typical configuration.

Comment: So, the only way to put 2 instances in different sites communicating with each other using private IPs is using the same VPC?

Comment: There could be other ways as well, but I am not sure.